# IIS 6.0 отдаёт старый файл

Tags: iis

Как заставить IIS 6.0 сбросить кеш? Беру файл, пакую в zip, выкладываю на сервер win2003 64bit (перезаписываю, пробовал даже удалять перемещать и т.п.). Скачиваю с нета - **файл старый**. Перезагружаю сервер/пул - то же самое. iisreset - не помогает.   Проходит **24** часа - проверяю - файл обновился. Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? Как оно лечится? Кеширует точно сервер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя много времени, обнаружил:

В IIS у свойтсв папок (или сайтов) на вкладке "HTTP Headers" вверху пункт "Enable content expiration" везде не стоит галочка. Поэтому скрипты "устаревают" если передают соответствующие заголовки, а файлы не понятно - у меня 24 часа. Проблема решилась - поставить галочку, и плюс радио-кнопку на первый пункт "Exprire immediately". Я поставил только для папки upload.