# Фильтр обрезает наименования элементов

Tags: javascript, c#, sharepoint

В стандартном dropdown фильтре по столбцу в представлении списка элементы фильтрации отображаются не полностью, а только первые 40 символов.

[image: Стандартный фильтр sharepoint]

В файле "layouts/15/core.js" нашел строку `if (h.length > 40) h = h.substring(0, 40) + "...";` Но если изменять 40 на что-то другое, то это никакого эффекта не дает. На странице фильтра "Filter.aspx" ничего связанного с этим не нашел. Есть ли варианты как обойти ограничение количества символов?

Comment: Попробуйте нажать Ctrl+F5. Скрипты кешируются. Плюс есть фишка, что скрипт может кешировать IIS - если Сtrl+F5 не поможет, смотрите Experied в IIS

Comment: IIS кеш смотреть тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558443/iis-6-0-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%91%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb/640378#640378

Comment: @nick_n_a, спасибо за информацию про кеш IIS, посмотрю как там что. а вообще Ctrl+F5, конечно, пробовал, и в исходном коде страницы изменения отображаются, только на фильтр они не влияют

Comment: " исходном коде страницы изменения отображаются, только на фильтр они не влияют"  - возможно есть ещё другие обработчики сокращений...

Comment: @nick_n_a , тоже так подумал, поэтому и решил создать вопрос, может кто-то в курсе что там к чему